# Do all isotopes have a half life?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I understand that some isotopes of an element have a shorter half life, and decay more quickly into other elements. Other isotopes are described as stable and no half life is stated. For elements that have a stable isotope, does this isotope still have a half life, just a very long one? Are there isotopes which do not decay spontaneously, or do all isotopes have a half life?

Comment: If proton decay is real all isotopes have a half life, those which are considered stable in a world without proton decay will just live much longer than the rest. So far we were not able to measure the decay time of protons, so this question is really not decided by experiments or observations, yet. I have a feeling that the majority of physicists in the field now believe in proton-decay as being more or less inevitable, but a theoretical physicist should chime in about that.

Comment: @CuriousOne yes I'd be interested to see an answer based on proton decay.

Comment: What does a githubphagocyte eat (phagocytose)?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance it was going to be just phagocyte to match my github name, but that was taken...

Comment: @CuriousOne But neutron decay is real, and not all isotopes containing neutrons have a half-life.

Comment: @rob: Neutrons in the nucleus are stabilized by their binding energy.

Comment: @CuriousOne Then the stability of a nucleus against the decay of its protons depends on the binding energy. The phase space will be different than for the low-energy neutron decay, though.

Comment: @rob: The decay will be modified but not suppressed because the ground state into which protons decay has zero energy. Photons always have the lowest ground state energy  and the decay of the universe into a cold photon bath is probably inevitable. The more interesting question is, what are photons decaying into?

Comment: @rob I'm not asking `"What is the threshold half life in order to arbitrarily label something as stable"`, I'm asking `"Are there isotopes that do not decay at all"`. So I don't see this as the same question as the proposed duplicate. Should I change parts of my wording to make the intent more clear?

Comment: @githubphagocyte I think the answer there addresses your question, since it argues that carbon-12 is really and truly a stable element.

Comment: @rob I agree that the answer is a better answer to this question than to that question. I don't think that makes the questions equivalent. Would you consider posting the answer here?

Answer (score 4):

This given link is list of different isotopes with half life time
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_radioactive_isotopes_by_half-life

The release of radiation by unstable nuclei is called radioactive decay. This process occurs naturally and cannot be influenced by chemical or physical processes. The release of radiation is also a random event and overtime the activity of the radioactive material decreases. It is not possible to predict when an individual nucleus in a radioactive material will decay. But it is possible to measure the time taken for half of the nuclei in a radioactive material to decay. This is called the half life of radioactive material or radioisotope.
This is the latest list of known isotopes :

http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/KnownIsotopes.html

given link below is I trust more 
http://ie.lbl.gov/education/isotopes.htm

Comment: The wikipedia list is marked as incomplete. Can you confirm whether all isotopes of all elements have a half life?

Answer (score 2):

Please see, like an atom that has a ground state, and in that state it would remain always if it not disturbed by some influence from outside, (some irradiation with other particles), so there are nuclei whose state is the ground state. Such nuclei have no excess of energy to get rid of.

Let me give some examples: there are nuclei with too many protons, s.t. teir configuration is unstable. They are likely to undergo $\beta ^+$ decay, and emit a positron. Other nuclei have to many neutrons, s.t. they may emit one or more neutrons, or may undergo $\beta ^-$ decay.

In short, yes, there are stable nuclei, or, in other words, there are ground states for nuclei.

Long lived unstable isotopes, are not in the ground states, but in some resonant states, very narrow from the point of view of the energy range encompassed by that resonance. The narrower the resonance, the longer is its half-life. But, I repeat, a resonant state, long lived as it may be, is not a ground state.

Comment: It's interesting to hear that there are nuclei in the ground state that are not susceptible to spontaneous decay. Could you include an example of an element that has such a nucleus?

Comment: Could you take another look at your opening sentence? I think you started saying one thing and ended up saying another - makes it confusing. Otherwise a nice post.